# React native code changes not reflecting on device

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native, visual-studio-code

Today morning on wards i am facing an issue with react native android build. The new changes in the code not reflecting on device. There is no build failure. I tried the followings

- Deleted and reinstalled the node modules
- react-native link
- ./gradlew clean
- react-native bundle --platform android --dev false --entry-file index.js --bundle-output android/app/src/main/assets/index.android.bundle --assets-dest android/app/src/main/res
- watchman shutdown-server
- rm -rf /usr/local/var/run/watchman && brew uninstall watchman && brew install watchman
- npm start - --reset-cache

My package.json

```
{
"name": "",
"version": "0.0.1",
"private": true,
"scripts": {
    "start": "node node_modules/react-native/local-cli/cli.js start",
    "test": "jest",
    "ipad": "react-native run-ios --simulator 'iPad Pro (10.5-inch) (12.0)' --configuration Debug"
},
"dependencies": {
    "@babel/runtime": "^7.2.0",
    "accordion-collapse-react-native": "^0.1.9",
    "aws-amplify": "^1.1.18",
    "aws-amplify-react-native": "^2.1.6",
    "aws-sdk": "^2.394.0",
    "buffer": "^5.2.1",
    "i18next": "^12.1.0",
    "moment": "^2.24.0",
    "nanoid": "^2.0.0",
    "native-base": "^2.8.1",
    "react": "^16.6.3",
    "react-i18next": "^8.3.8",
    "react-native": "^0.57.8",
    "react-native-app-intro-slider": "^2.0.1",
    "react-native-check-box": "^2.1.7",
    "react-native-collapsible": "^1.4.0",
    "react-native-fetch-blob": "^0.10.8",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "^1.0.10",
    "react-native-image-crop-picker": "^0.21.3",
    "react-native-image-resizer": "^1.0.0",
    "react-native-img-button": "^1.0.1",
    "react-native-keyboard-aware-scroll-view": "^0.8.0",
    "react-native-keyboard-manager": "^4.0.13-10",
    "react-native-keyboard-spacer": "^0.4.1",
    "react-native-languages": "^3.0.1",
    "react-native-linear-gradient": "^2.5.3",
    "react-native-locale-detector": "^1.0.1",
    "react-native-material-dropdown": "^0.11.1",
    "react-native-material-ripple": "^0.8.0",
    "react-native-modal-datetime-picker": "^6.0.0",
    "react-native-paper": "^2.15.2",
    "react-native-segmented-control-tab": "^3.3.1",
    "react-native-signature-pad-react-16": "^0.4.0",
    "react-native-size-matters": "^0.1.4",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "^6.1.0",
    "react-navigation": "^2.18.2",
    "react-redux": "^5.1.1",
    "redux": "^4.0.1",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.3.0",
    "remote-redux-devtools": "^0.5.16",
    "rnkit-alert-view": "^0.1.2"
},
"devDependencies": {
    "babel-jest": "23.6.0",
    "jest": "23.6.0",
    "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "0.49.2",
    "react-test-renderer": "16.6.1"
},
"jest": {
    "preset": "react-native"
},
"rnpm": {
    "assets": [
        "./src/assets/fonts"
    ]
}
}
```

Comment: usually when I have this problem there is always an error in the terminal, but not in the debugger. So seemingly the app is running fine and the build doesn't have any errors but there is actually  an error in the terminal and its causing this UI not updating issue

Answer (score 2):

Don't use `react-native bundle --platform android --dev false --entry-file index.js --bundle-output android/app/src/main/assets/index.android.bundle --assets-dest android/app/src/main/res` for running react native in Android. This command bundles the JS server within the package(APK). So there will be no communication with your metro server that runs on the system.

Use `react-native run-android` command for debugging the app. In this js server won't ship with package. So the changes will reflect when you refresh the app

Comment: I have tried the command but still not able to refresh the code until I go to the module and press the Ctrl+S to save the code.

Comment: @UserSharma you must save the code in your files. otherwise, it won't reflect in the app

Comment: I am talking about the node modules. Let's say I have upgraded the version of one node module from the NPM server and then I have run the android debug build then the updated code in the new version does not reflect in the app until I go to each and every file of the node module and press Ctrl+S.